# How to load resource files in java based on the environment?

Tags: java, resources

So my team inherited a really large Java repository. It has a configuration file in the packed jar file.

At several places in the code, it loads the configuration file as below:

```
 InputStream in = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("configfile.config");
```

Now, based on the environment I want to be able to load a different config file.
On dev, I want to be able to load configfile.dev.config and on prod I want to be able to load configfile.prod.config.

What would be the most non-invasive, clean solution to this problem?

Comment: What variety of application is this--desktop application, war, standalone jar? Are you using a framework such as Spring?

Comment: It uses some EJB and talks to a SQLserver and dumps out some data onto the Harddrive. This is basically a KTLO task the repo itself is deprecated. We use Py4j to talk to it.

Comment: How do you launch the task?

Comment: java8 -jar jarname.
The configuration file is within the jar.

Comment: Then we separately launch the python tasks that interface with this.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't seem to have framework support for this and are launching from the command line, the best approach is to use a system property. There are two common approaches:

- Use a property such as `config.location`, where the value is a URI to the config file. This is more flexible and allows you to provide a new config file at runtime, but it makes it a bit more complicated to refer to one inside a jar (those URIs get long and need shell escaping).
- Use a property such as `config.profile`, where the value is a profile identifier such as `dev` or `prod`. Name your included config files either `/dev/config.file` or `/config-dev.file`, and assemble the appropriate template name from the property.

Based on your preference for including the multiple configurations inside the jar, the second option is probably a better fit.

Comment: Is there by any chance any clever hacks I can use with classpath for this problem?

Comment: @Aditya The configuration files are in the same general location on the classpath. Distinguish them by path name, either with a directory or a filename suffix.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a spring boot application? If yes, you can use different profiles like dev, testing and load the resource as per the profile.- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

If it's not spring boot application, then you can pass the profile value as JVM argument and use it in the code to load respective resouce.

```
  value=System.getProperty("profile");
```

Pass the profile value while running the application as -

```
  -Dprofile=test
```

You can use the passed profile and load respective file accordingly.

```
  InputStream in = 
  classLoader.getResourceAsStream(value);
```